# Markdown not correctly generating links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

Reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication) page, and one of the articles prev/next links weren't linking. Went to fix it, but finally decided it was correct (or at least consistent with other working posts), so I assume it is a bug in the markdown.

[Part 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication#477580)'s prev and next links **do work** (for reference).

[Part 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication#477583)'s prev and next links **do not work**.

Also note that the (presumably) JS preview for Part 3 shows it not working, but when generated, it does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not wrong, we just stopped supporting anchor-only forms of URLs, e.g.

`[example link](#anchortext)`

Urls need to be in the form of

`/foo`

or

`http://example.com/foo`

Comment: Any idea why half of my `http://tinyurl.com/so-hints` http://tinyurl.com/so-hints in comments don't hyperlink automatically?

Comment: @sarn what? it looks correct to me

Comment: Yeah, worked here, but I had to manually hyperlink it on my first comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95183/email-generated-by-asp-net-not-displaying-image-in-mac-os-but-diplaying-in-window).

Comment: @sarnold I see that is triggering the "can't mix 2 different kinds of links in a comment" behavior. I'll ask Ben about that.

Comment: @Jeff, just knowing that will save me from a handful of silly edits. Thanks! :)

Comment: @sarnold: It's going to work again after the next build.